# C++ - Copying of objects of derived class into objects of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

We can not copy a derived object into an object of the base class due to the restrictions of the overloading operator `=`. Then, why can we copy the address of a derived object into the pointer of a base class ? Shouldn't it be the other way around because the derived object is of larger size that the base class object. In fact, when I tried it, I got an error which said that `the conversion of a base object to the derived object is not allowed`. Can you please tell me why? I am unable to find anything relevant information on the internet.
The code is as follows:-

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class employee
{
    protected:
        string name;
        double pay;
    public:
        employee(string ename,double payRate)
        {
            name = ename;
            pay = payRate;
        }
        virtual double GrossPay(int days)
        {
            return pay*days;
        }
        virtual string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
};
class manager:public employee
{
    private:
        bool salaried;
    public:
        manager(string ename,double payRate,bool isSalaried):employee(ename,payRate)
        {
            salaried = isSalaried;
        }
        virtual double GrossPay(int days)
        {
            if(salaried)
                return pay;
            else
                return pay*days;
        }
};
int main(void)
{
    employee* emp2;
    employee emp3("Bill",350);
    manager mgr3("Alice",200,true);
    emp2 = &emp3;
    cout<<emp2->getName()<<" earns "<<emp2->GrossPay(40)<<endl;
    emp2 = &mgr3;
    cout<<emp2->getName()<<" earns "<<emp2->GrossPay(40)<<endl; // The code works till here
    //The problematic part starts from here:- 
    manager* mgr6;                                          
    employee emp5("NewBill",300);
    mgr6 = &emp5;
    cout<<mgr6->getName()<<" earns "<<mgr6->GrossPay(40)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: The error that I showed is the simplified of what the compiler actually displayed.

Comment: I amn't sure I understood you correctly. You can do - `Base obj = Derived();`. However, the object is sliced. Please post the test program you tried.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Are you asking why you can't assign `Derived* obj = (Base*)whatever`? It has nothing to do with sizes, because Pointers are all the same size. It has to do that you can't guarantee that that (Base*) points to a Derived object, it could be any other derived class.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams "pointers are all the same size" Actually, this isn't guaranteed to be true. Standard doesn't require this. (for example far and near pointers for segmented memory models)

Comment: @milleniumbug Wow...+1 you learn something new every day...sometimes I am happy I learned to program after it got simpler, sometimes I think it has just made me a relatively sloppy programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
manager* mgr6;                                          
employee emp5("NewBill",300);
mgr6 = &emp5;
```

In your example, `manager` class is derived from the `employee` class. So, `emp5` is a base class object. It has no knowledge about the derived class members.

And `mgr6` is of type `manager *` and it trying to point to `emp5`. As said earlier, `emp5` has no derived class sub-object for the assignment operation to work.

However, this works.

```
employee* emp2;
manager mgr3("Alice",200,true);
emp2 = &mgr3;
```

Because, `mgr3` has both the derived and base class sub-objects.

EDIT: Corrected emp3 to mgr3 in the last line

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert a base object to a derived object because there isn't enough information. It's like having an empty sandwich and pretending its a BLT!

The problem with downcasting an object is that the derived class may be bigger so wouldn't fit  in the available memory but the pointer is allowed since the derived class is exactly and more of the base class. Continuing the sandwich metaphor: if you ignore the filling, a BLT is just an empty sandwich.

In your example `mgr6` thinks it is pointing to a `manager` but say there was a getter for `bool salaried` called `IsSalaried()` what should happen if when you call `mgr6->IsSalaried()`. This is obviously not logical therefore it is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The inheritance relationship is often described as "Is A"  so for example if you have a base class of vehicle and two derived classes MotorCycle and Semi then

```
  Motorcycle *m = new Motorcycle();
  Semi *s = new Semi();

  Vehicle *v1 = m;
  Vehicle *v2 = s;
```

is fine. Motorcycle is a Vehicle and Semi is a Vehicle.
 You can call any method you want on v1 and v2 and there will be an implementation of that method.

On the other hand if you then said:

```
  Motorcycle m2 = v2;
```

You would be in trouble.   Vehicle is not (necessarily) a motorcycle.

Suppose the Motorcycle class had a method named wheelie() that is not in the Vehicle class (for obvious reasons)   After that assignment you could say:
      M2->wheelie();

and your poor semi wouldn't know how to do it.   Thus the cast from base class to derived class is not legal.

Comment: If you have RTTI enabled, then you can use the <dynamic_cast> operator to cast from a Vehicle to a Motorcycle.  It will check the actual type of the object and fail if the cast is not valid.